# Return Seq[Row] from Spark-Scala UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am using Spark with Scala to do some data processing. I have XML data mapped to dataframe. I am passing a Row as parameter to the UDF and trying to extract two complex types objects as a list. Spark is giving me following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.Row is not supported

```
def testUdf = udf((testInput: Row) => {
  val firstObject = testInput.getAs[Row]("Object1")
  val secondObject = testInput.getAs[Row]("Object2")
  val returnObject = Seq[firstObject,secondObject]

  returnObject
})
```

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UDF cannot return `Row` objects. Return type has to be one of the types enumerated in the column Value type in Scala in the [Data Types table](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types).

Good news is there should be no need for UDF here. If `Object1` and `Object2` *have the same schema* (it wouldn't work otherwise anyway) you can use `array` function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.select(array(col("Object1"), col("Object2"))
```

or

```
df.select(array(col("path.to.Object1"), col("path.to.Object2"))
```

if `Object1` and `Object2` are not top level columns.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest one alternative way which can be used if schema for object1 and object2 are different and you get to return the row.
Basically to return row , you simply return a case class having the schema of Row objects which in this case is object1 and object2 which themselves seem to be rows

so do the following

```
case class Object1(<add the schema here>)

case class Object2(<add the schema here>)

case class Record(object1:Object1,object2:Object2)
```

Now inside the UDF , you can create object1 and object2 using firstObject and secondObject

then

```
val record = Record(object1,object2)
```

Then you can return the `record`

In this you can return rows even if schema not same or some processing required.

I know that this doesn't actually pertain to your question , but this question seemed a correct opportunity to tell about this concept.