# UDF registeration error: Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] is not supported

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When register the UDF function getting below error, other UDF function are working but only this UDF giving issue.

Error:
**Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] is not supported**

UDF registration:

```
spark.udf.register("udfname",udf_name _)
```

UDF code:-

```
 def udf_name(paramter1: String,Parameter2:String): DataFrame = {

val df= spark.textFile("file path")

if (paramter1!= null) {
  val out = df.selectdf("Col1"),
    df("Col2"),
    df("Col3")).filter($"Col4" === Parameter1&&
      $"col5" === Parameter1)
  return df_out
```

Once I applied filter on the dataframe , the return type changed to Dataset[Row] , why it is changed to Dataset instead of Dataframe.

Comment: UDF cannot return DataFrame.

Please check answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41515702/return-seqrow-from-spark-scala-udf

Comment: is there any alternative ? ,So that I can achieve the same

Answer (score 0):

Loading file in UDF looks very strange. Alternatives:

1. File "file path" can be loaded in dataframe before processing. Then "file path" dataFrame can be joined with the main dataframe.
2. File "file path" can be loaded into broadcast variable. Several UDF can be used for extract value from broadcast variable to concrete column.